# Is there any way to avoid being dismounted whilst interacting with items outside of Draenor?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The Tier 1 Stables in the Garrison has the following perk:

> Also allows you to remain mounted while interacting with objects in outdoor Draenor zones.

This is pretty great if you're doing a lot of questing. I'm working on Loremaster of Kalimdor and it would be wonderful to have this feature there. Is there any way to get a similar effect to the Stables effect outside of Draenor?

Comment: Be a Druid in flight form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated for Legion expansion:**

The blacksmithing item [Demonsteel Stirrups](http://www.wowhead.com/item=136708/demonsteel-stirrups) allows interacting with items while in the Broken Isles.

For older content this is not possible.

Footnote: Druids in travel form and shamans in ghost wolf (can get mount speed in Broken Isles with [Rehgar Earthfury](http://www.wowhead.com/champion=612/rehgar-earthfury) as Bodyguard) can interact with items, this is not the same as being mounted but close.

Comment: ...as long as you're editing this, you might want to change the part about glyphs as well because pretty much all non-cosmetic glyphs were removed from the game in Legion.

Comment: @Powerlord you are right, thanks for the reminder.